# Component is part of declaration of both the modules:AppRoutingModule and AppModule

Tags: angular, module, routes, components

I am trying to separate my routing module from another module by defining it in its own typescript file. But I get the above error:**Component is part of declaration of both the modules:AppRoutingModule and AppModule**

Sharing both modules below:

**AppRoutingModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { AdminHomeComponent } from './nav/adminhome.component'
import { UserHomeComponent } from './nav/userhome.component'
import { ContactComponent } from './nav/contact.component'
import { LandingComponent } from './nav/mainhome.component'
import { LoginFormComponent } from './nav/login.component'


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent },
    { path: 'adminHome', component: AdminHomeComponent },
    { path: 'userHome', component: UserHomeComponent },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
    { path: '', component: LandingComponent }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**AppModule**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule} from './app.routing'

import { AdminHomeComponent } from './nav/adminhome.component'
import { UserHomeComponent } from './nav/userhome.component'
import { ContactComponent } from './nav/contact.component'
import { LandingComponent } from './nav/mainhome.component'
import { LoginFormComponent } from './nav/login.component'
import { ShareService } from './nav/ShareService'
//import { PaginationModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
//import { Ng2PaginationModule } from 'ng2-pagination';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, AppRoutingModule ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, AdminHomeComponent, UserHomeComponent, ContactComponent, LandingComponent, LoginFormComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [ShareService]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

I followed https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html routing docs but landed in such error.

Can someone see if there's some mistake that might be there in the code. Thanks.

Comment: Does the error message say what component is part of both modules?

Comment: yes. AdminHomeComponent.

Comment: Is this reproducible in a plunk?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should move `AdminHomeComponent` and all other components that are referenced in `AppRoutingModule` out of `AppModule` into a different module(s) and add this module(s) to `imports` of `AppRoutingModule`.

Comment: But what's wrong with my implementation. It is as per the angular docs. And it would be an overkill to define one more module just to define the components again.

Comment: AFAIK the components added by the router are added automatically to `entryComponents` and `declarations` of the module where they are used in routes, when not found in an imported module. I don't know of docs (doesn't mean there are none), because components can't be part of more than one module this causes the error.

Comment: But did you check the documentation. Why doesn't it mention such thing?

Comment: No, I didn't check the documentation. There are lots of docs about the router and NgModule.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I should create a new `module` and in it I should import all of my `components`. After that I should just `export`  it and make use of it in `AppRoutingModule` and `AppModule`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Exactly. Create a `MyFeatureModule`, add all components to `declarations: [...]` and `exports: [...]` and then add `MyFeatureModule` to `imports: [...]` of `AppRoutingModule` and `AppModule`. You could also create 2 feature modules, one with components used by the router to import in the `AppRoutingModule` and another one with all other components to import in `AppModule`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136476/discussion-between-aakash-thakur-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1):

*I cannot comment I will write this as an answer.*

This is weird, the code as it is should work. I tried the same logic and it worked for me.

Can you try removing the `AdminHomeComponent` from the `appRoutes`, and see if it's only `AdminHomeComponent` or the other components raise the same issue too.

If you have the same issue with other components too. Try declaring them ONLY in your routing module and see if it works (this is not a good practice though).

There is another approach to it:

**app-routing.module.ts**:

```
import { Host, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { OtherComponent } from './other.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'other', component: OtherComponent},
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**app.module.ts**:

```
import {  routing } from './app-routing.module';
import { OtherComponent } from './other.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    OtherComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  routing
],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*Personally, I would do what was suggested in the other 2 answers.*

By the way, do you have any other modules in your app?

Comment: Its throwing error in each and every modules as all of them are repeated in the modules. Your answer also doesn't point in the direction of the solution as it has also imported components in multiple modules and that is what the concern is.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible!

You could create a Module including just that component and import it to your modules.

Comment: 1. Create new module ( for example AdminModule)
2. Define AdminHomeComponent in this module 
3. Export AdminHomeComponent from this module
4. Import AdminModule to your modules where you need AdminHomeComponent

Comment: Thats exactly what I did as suggested by Gunter in other answer. If you see the chat with Gunter, you will get to know that I followed this process only.